How to resolve error with the parameter code?
I am trying to return true or false statement based on a value in the Net Framework Release DWORD file
Script:
Get-ItemPropertyValue -LiteralPath 'HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full' -Name Release) -ge 528040

Error Message:
Get-ItemPropertyValue : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ge'.
At line:1 char:108
+ ... E\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full' -Name Release -ge 528040
+                                                                ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ItemPropertyValue], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyValueCommand

Question: What is missing from the script for the ge parameter to work?
Was expecting a true or false statement

The "script" you've posted is syntactically invalid (the're no ( matching the ) before -ge), and it's clearly not the code you're running - the ) isn't present in the error message. Please post the exact code you're having trouble with

Hi Mathias, it was down to the syntax of the () not being incorporated at the start of the code. Changed this and it is now running.

That makes sense, good to hear :) Feel free to answer your own question below

The syntax in the code was incorrect. The () was not added correctly to the code. This has now been modified and is working as required.
